# How to convert sql table into a pyspark/python data structure and return back to sql in databricks notebook

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, databricks

I am running a sql notebook on databricks. I would like to analyze a table with half a billion records in it. I can run simple sql queries on the data. However, I need to change the date column type from str to date.

Unfortunately, update/alter statements do not seem to be supported by sparkSQL so it seems I cannot modify the data in the table.

**What would be the one-line of code that would allow me to convert the SQL table to a python data structure (in pyspark) in the next cell?** 
Then I could modify the file and return it to SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dataFrame = sqlContext.sql('select * from myTable')
```

Comment: Thanks!
And How would I return it back to sql so I can go back to querying it in sql in the next cell?
Probably also one line.
Is it something like `dataFrame.to_sql` (Have no clue. Just made it up to give you an idea of what I mean)

Comment: @Semihcan, you want the registerTempTable function http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
df=sqlContext.sql("select * from table")
```

To convert dataframe back to sql view,

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("myview")
```